# Is there any difference between "EMERGENCY LANDING" and "FORCED LANDING"?

Tags: landing

Emergency landings and/or forced landings are stressful situations, but talking about meanings, are they the same, please?

Answer (score 2):

Not all forced landings are emergencies, and not all emergencies are forced landings! (See below)

In general, the term "Emergency Landing" is a superset which covers a bunch of different scenarios where a landing is not quite to plan. Such as

- Forced landing due to mechanical failure. Note that a forced landing can *absolutely* be at an airfield. It can also be in a literal field.
- Precautionary landing, such as where continued flight is possible but inadvisable
- Ditching in a body of water
- Belly landing due to inoperable landing gear

A forced landing can also be one where the pilot is forced to land due to military interception, which is not always an emergency.

This is all covered in great detail [here](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Emergency_Landing)

---

The FAA also publish [some useful information on this subject](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/airplane_handbook/media/19_afh_ch17.pdf) which repeats much of the above information, reproduced below for clarity

> **Types of Emergency Landings**
> The different types of emergency landings are defined as
> follows:
> • Forced landing—an immediate landing, on or off an
> airport, necessitated by the inability to continue further
> flight. A typical example of which is an airplane forced
> down by engine failure.
> • Precautionary landing—a premeditated landing, on
> or off an airport, when further flight is possible but
> inadvisable. Examples of conditions that may call for
> a precautionary landing include deteriorating weather,
> being lost, fuel shortage, and gradually developing
> engine trouble.
> • Ditching—a forced or precautionary landing on water

Comment: In the UK Forced Landing = Emergency Landing

Comment: @GdD I'd like to see some source for that, it would make a good addition to this answer. In 20 years of flying in the UK, I'm not sure I've seen any official definitions

Comment: @GdD Also, as my first sentence alludes to, there has been the occasional military interception which force a landing at stansted (usually) which are not emergencies. So not all forced landings = emergency landings. The terms _are_ used fairly interchangably - does not mean that they are the exact same thing.

Comment: I've only heard "forced landing" synonymous as an unscheduled landing without power. e.g. PFL. I wouldn't consider an *enforced* landing by somebody to be a "forced landing" in this context.

Comment: I sort of agree, I've only heard it used in the same context. But, that's not what ICAO says. Interested in any sources other than "Thats what I always thought"